# orderby in query_posts

Tags: customization

I have the following line to change my wp query slightly. The posts are by this ordered by the value in the custom field "wpfp_favorites". The value is allways an integer. Posts with value 0-9 is sorted correctly, but when a post has value 10 (or more i guess) its not listed above posts with 9.

```
query_posts('meta_key=wpfp_favorites&orderby=meta_value');
```

What is wrong? You can see the problem in "action" here: http://hverdagskupp.no/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

take a look here:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

you need to change orderby=meta_value to orderby=meta_value_num -> than you value gets treated as an integer not a string!

```
query_posts('meta_key=wpfp_favorites&orderby=meta_value_num');
```

i would pass an array instead of a string like

```
query_posts( array( 'meta_key'=>'wpfp_favorites', 'orderby'=>'meta_value_num' );
```

you dont have to but its easier to read and WordPress converts that string to an array anyway....

Comment: glad i could help after so many people and times somebody has helped me...